# Enable default secomp and apparmor profiles , cluster level

Tags: kubernetes, apparmor, seccomp

Can I enable, on the cluster level, for the pods to use default secomp and apparmor profiles or do I need to make an admission controller of my own to insert the innotation to the objects?

Leaving it to users is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already the [`PodSecurityPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/) object which essentially is an implementation of an admission controller. You can control the [`seccomp`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#seccomp) and [`apparmor`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/clusters/apparmor/#podsecuritypolicy-annotations) profiles using annotations in the PodSecurityPolicy:

For example (as described in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#example-policies)), notice the 'default' in the annotation:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: restricted
  annotations:
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: 'docker/default'
    apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: 'runtime/default'
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName:  'docker/default'
    apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName:  'runtime/default'
spec:
...
```

Note that [Seccomp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#seccomp) is alpha and [Apparmor](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/clusters/apparmor/) is beta as of this writing.